# Alternative to Actemra 400 mg

Tags: injections, arthritis

There is a little bit of Panic for Actemra 400 mg Injection in India these days but I see that Actemra 162 mg is available. If in an unfortunate situation one cannot find Actemra 400mg dose can monitored multiple dose of Actemra 162 mg along with 80mg dose used under the supervision of doctor? If any doctor here can answer the same that would be great!